# food for thought: return in if statement

Tags: javascript

I can put a return anywhere such as in a function, in an if block, case block.

How come this doesn't work:

```
     (x == "good") ? (return("works")):"";
```

UPDATE: I know I can do this:

```
     return (x == "good") ? ("works"):"";
```

Just want to know why the first case isn't acceptable.

Comment: "doesn't work" - can you be more precise? What is the error message?

Comment: Just a language implementation choice.  Wasn't implemented to work that way...

Comment: Check out my answer - it explains the "why".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the [grammar of a ternary operation is this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

> condition ? expr1 : expr2

And a return statement isn't technically considered an expression.

---

Edit: here's some more info. The above explains it in terms of the grammar of the language, but here's a little bit about the reasoning of why.

I've actually dug into this before, because I've always thought it would be cool to be able to do stuff like:

```
someFlag && return;
```

Rather than

```
if (someFlag) return;
```

The problem, however, is that expressions always need to evaluate to something. This requirement is at odds with the role of the return statement, however, which along with (optionally) returning a result, also immediately terminates execution of the current function.  This termination of the current function is logically inconsistent with the need to evaluate the value of the return statement itself, if it were indeed an expression.

Given that inconsistency, the language authors apparently chose to not allow return statements to act as expressions.  Hope I managed to word that in a way that makes sense.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks. I actually mean to say "isn't" instead of "is", but yes - that was fudged.

Comment: I think I need to know a little more

Comment: Because there is no semicolon after the return statement. That's why?

Comment: No, the semicolon actually isn't the issue. It's because the ternary operation expects *expressions* on either side of the `:`, whereas a return statement is not a valid expression, as defined by the language.

Answer (score 3):

are you trying to do this:

```
return (x == "good") ? "works":"";
```

return isn't a function, so return("works") isn't correct. 
alternatively you could also do:

```
var x = "bad";

var y = (x=="good")? "works" : "";

return y;
```

but this is more verbose.  So to answer your question, you can put return anywhere in a function, but anything after it won't be executed. so

```
function x ()
{
   var str = "";

   return "I love puppies.";

   str = "me too!" //this won't ever execute, because return exits the function.
}
```

The one exception to this is variable declaration, because variables are automatically declared at the beginning no matter where you put them.

```
function y (){
  return "";

   var x; 
}
```

is really:

```
function y (){
   var x;

   return "";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `return` keyword should come first:

```
return (x == "good") ? "works": "";
```

The reason is that `return x;` is a statement. You can't use `(return x)` as an expression.

All expressions can be used where a statement is expected, but not all statements can be used where an expression is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying if x is "good", then return, otherwise do nothing else? In that case,

```
if (x == "good") return "works";
```

does the trick. Furthermore, `return` is not a function, it is a javascript token, so no parentheses should be  used with `return`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`return` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) marks the beginning of a statement. It is not an expression, which you could use with the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 0):

Based off of this [grammar](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/jsspec11/llr.htm)  for javascript, The ternary operator is defined as :

```
OrExpression ? AssignmentExpression : AssignmentExpression
```

Whereas `return` is a `statement` (well, the beginning of one anyways).

In any case messing with control flow in an "expressive" (read: "I want to be clever") form like ternary expressions would not be recommended by anyone I know. an if statement is the same amount of characters:

```
  if(x==good) return x;
    (x==good)?(return x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because ["Almost everything is an expression"](http://www.mail-archive.com/es-discuss@mozilla.org/msg11218.html) hasn't made it into the language yet.

Answer (score -1):

All the answers that begin with "return" are doing different behavior from what I think the OP intended in his ternary operation.  I'm guessing the OP wants

```
x == "good" ? return "works" : "";
```

to mean

```
if(x == "good") {
    return works;
}
else {
    ""; //does nothing because the statement ""; has no side effects
}
```

It doesn't do this because the format is

```
statement1 ? statement2 : statement3;
```

All statements may have side-effects but only the return value (in the case of statement1, just the truthiness of it) are considered by the ternary operator.

Even though the ? : is best read in terms of "if" and "then," when thinking closer to the level of syntax it should be thought of as an expression that factors into side-effects and a return value.  If you understand the difference between x++ and ++x, you will be able to understand the ternary operator.

By way of example, here are some illegal statements that are illegal for the same reason.

```
if( (return 5) == 5) {
     //...
}

if (loadUserStats(return userId)) == "FAILED") {
    throw error("oops");
}

x = return  y++;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. If the format *was* `statement1 ? statement2 : statement3`, then the provided code would be valid, since return statements are... statements. The format is actually `condition ? expr1 : expr2`, and given that return statements aren't expressions, it is resultantly invalid.

Comment: What word do I mean instead of "statement"?  "expression"?  Was more concerned about emphasizing that it's not "condition" so much as any expression, because languages like C and Javascript endow all objects (primitive or not) with truthiness.  If by "condition" you mean "an expression only whose truthiness is evaluated" then OK.

Comment: `expression` and `statement` are both defined explicitly within the grammar of the language. Given a ternary operation which is to be expressed as `condition ? expression : expression`, the language will allow anything that's actually considered an expression within the ternary operator (truthiness is somewhat of a side issue here). The problem is that, grammatically speaking, `return` statements are *not* considered `expressions`, and therefore violate the expected syntax.

Comment: I'm almost there, need to know the difference between a statement and expression. If anything includes a return keyword, it's automatically not an expression